# How to specify Beta version of a Swift Dependency using Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I want to use the beta version of a swift package in one of my project that uses Swift Package Manager. Below is the code of my `Package.swift`

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "firstProj",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/ankurp/Cent.git", Version(6, 0, 0, prereleaseIdentifiers: ["beta"]))
    ])
```

There is a `6.0.0-beta` tag version of the package available on github as seen by this URL https://github.com/ankurp/Cent/releases/tag/6.0.0-beta

When I try to build using `swift build` it throws the following error

```
error: The dependency graph could not be satisfied because an update to `https://github.com/ankurp/Cent.git' is required
```

My question is how can I specify a beta version of the dependency and in my case the package has a tag of `6.0.0-beta`

I took a look at this but it did not help https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#version

Answer (score 3):

The dependency resolution is being actively worked on, and the package manager doesn't automatically handle this situation yet.

This error should resolve itself if you run `swift package update`.

Answer (score 0):

Running this in terminal in the package file path worked for me.

```
swift package update
```